# Difference between AFNetworking and Postman response with JSON request

Tags: objective-c, node.js, cocoa, afnetworking-2

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this when I POST with AFNetworking (wrong):

```
[ '0',
  '1',
  '7',
  '0',
  '2',
  '94',
  '0',
  '3',
  '41',
  '0',
  '4',
  '5',
  '0',
  '5',
  '51',
  '0',
  '6',
  '3',
  '0',
  '7',
  '40',
  '0',
  '8',
  '18',
  '0',
  '9',
  '12',
  '0',
  '10',
  '10',
  '1',
  '11',
  '9',
  '2',
  '12',
  '4',
  '2',
  '13',
  '17',
  '2',
  '14',
  '25',
  '2',
  '15',
  '16',
  '2',
  '16',
  '15',
  '2',
  '17',
  '21',
  '2',
  '18',
  '35',
  '2',
  '19',
  '37',
  '2',
  '20',
  '34',
  '2',
  '21',
  '32',
  '3',
  '22',
  '96' ]
```

but I get this when I POST with postman (correct)?

```
[ { riderId: 7, placeId: 1, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 94, placeId: 2, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 41, placeId: 3, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 5, placeId: 4, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 51, placeId: 5, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 3, placeId: 6, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 40, placeId: 7, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 18, placeId: 8, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 12, placeId: 9, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 10, placeId: 10, eventCategoryId: 0 },
  { riderId: 9, placeId: 11, eventCategoryId: 1 },
  { riderId: 4, placeId: 12, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 17, placeId: 13, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 25, placeId: 14, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 16, placeId: 15, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 15, placeId: 16, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 21, placeId: 17, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 35, placeId: 18, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 37, placeId: 19, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 34, placeId: 20, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 32, placeId: 21, eventCategoryId: 2 },
  { riderId: 96, placeId: 22, eventCategoryId: 3 } ]
```

That's a node.js response btw. Same endpoint and json data being posted on both.

Thoughts?

It's just a simple NSMutableDictionary that I'm passing. Here is my AFNetworking submission code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:@"http://192.168.20.230:3000/api/v1/test" parameters:submission success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"responseObject: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Comment: What is the response supposed to look like? Neither of your alleged results are valid JSON.

Comment: @user3477950 That's the response from node.js. It's supposed to look like the Postman version. Same input on both. Only difference is what the request is going through. Postman or AFNetworking.

Comment: Sorry I also meant to mention that it's a json request. The response doesn't need to be valid json. I'm really just trying to figure out why the responses are different with the exact same request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently I needed to set the requestSerializer.

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

I thought that json was AFNetworking's default so setting that would be redundant. Ah well.

Full working code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"http://192.168.20.230:3000/api/v1/test" parameters:submission success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"responseObject: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```